# I want to edit single record from multiple records

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

Hi this is mouli and i am new for visualforce, i want to edit a single record from multiple records available in a visualforce page i tryed but when click on edit button  it is enabling all the records instad of perticular record please help me to solve this code.

**Page:**

```
<apex:page controller="MyController11" tabStyle="account">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="My Accounts">
                <apex:pageblocktable value="{!myaccounts}" var="acct">
                       <apex:column >
                         <apex:facet name="header">{!$ObjectType.Account.fields.Name.label}</apex:facet>
                         <apex:outputField value="{!acct.Name}" rendered="{!!isEditEnabled}" />
                         <apex:inputField value="{! acct.Name}" rendered="{!isEditEnabled}"/><br></br>
                       </apex:column>
                       <apex:column >
                       <apex:facet name="header">{!$ObjectType.Account.fields.Name.label}</apex:facet>  
                         <apex:outputField value="{!acct.type}" rendered="{!!isEditEnabled}" />
                         <apex:inputField value="{! acct.type}" rendered="{!isEditEnabled}"/><br></br>
                        </apex:column>
                        <apex:column >
                            <apex:commandbutton value="Edit" action="{!edit}" />
                            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" />
                        </apex:column>
                </apex:pageblocktable>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller :**

```
public class MyController11 {

    public List<Account> myAccounts;
        public Boolean isEditEnabled;

    public MyController11(){
        myAccounts = new List<Account>();
                isEditEnabled = false;
    }

    public List<Account> getMyAccounts(){
        myAccounts = [select Id,name,type from Account WHERE (owner.id =: userinfo.getuserid())];            
        return myAccounts;           
    }   

    public PageReference edit() {

    if(isEditEnabled = true}{

    }       
    return null;    
    }

    public PageReference save() {  
        update myAccounts;
        isEditEnabled = false;
        return null;    
    }

    public Boolean getIsEditEnabled(){
        return isEditEnabled;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I understand is that you are displaying a list of Accounts and the user should be able to edit and save one of them. So the below code is one way of doing this.

**VF page**

```
<apex:pageBlock id="blockId">
    <apex:pageblocktable value="{!myaccounts}" var="acct">
         <apex:column>
             <apex:inputField value="{!acct.name}" rendered="{!tobeEdited == acct.id}"/>
             <apex:outputField value="{!acct.name}"  rendered="{!!(tobeEdited == acct.id)}"/>
         </apex:column>
         <apex:column>
             <apex:inputField value="{!acct.type}"  rendered="{!tobeEdited == acct.id}"/>
             <apex:outputField value="{!acct.type}"   rendered="{!!(tobeEdited == acct.id)}"/>             
         </apex:column>
         <apex:column>
              <apex:commandbutton value="Edit" rerender="blockId" rendered="{!!(tobeEdited == acct.id)}">
                  <apex:param assignTo="{!tobeEdited}" value="{!acct.id}" name="ittobeedited"/>
              </apex:commandbutton>
              <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!saveRecord}" reRender="blockId" rendered="{!tobeEdited == acct.id}"/>
         </apex:column>
   </apex:pageblocktable>
</apex:pageBlock>   
</apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public class MyController11 {
    public List<Account> myAccounts;
    public id tobeEdited{get; set;}     

    public MyController11(){

    }

    public List<Account> getMyAccounts(){
        myAccounts = [select Id,name,type from Account WHERE (owner.id =: userinfo.getuserid())];            
        return myAccounts;           
    }  

    public void saveRecord(){
        Account tobeupdated;
        for(Account temp:myAccounts){
            if(temp.id==tobeEdited){
                tobeupdated = temp;   
                break;
            }
        }
        update tobeupdated;
        tobeEdited = null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the sample code for edit single record from multiple
http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Multiple-Row-Editing-In-Salesforce-1706.php